# Flashing black and white screen when returning to GUI

Tags: 12.04, screen

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and while experimenting with the software, I have encountered this problem:

I learnt that ctrl + alt + F1~F6 can bring me to the terminal (Or was it a virtual terminal? I am not entirely sure on that). Either way, the terminal works, but the real problem starts when I try to exit the terminal with alt + F7 to get back to my GUI. The screen starts flashing in black and white, where I could only force reboot with the power button.

Generally I can still access the GUI by restarting, but the bug happens when I switch between the GUI and the terminal.

I also notice that returning from suspend also results in the same error.

I am completely new to Linux, especially to its command line, I would appreciate that you would keep the answers plain and easy.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I should add that as a graphic driver I have Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV710(, and linux 3.5.0-26-generic.

Answer (score 0):

"I also notice that returning from suspend also results in the same error."

I have same problem.

My main concern was inability to use suspend (I don't really have reason to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd> terminals).

Anyway I turned off option that turns off my screen after being inactive for some time and
it turned out that now I am able to suspend.

So if you want to avoid those flashes while "waking up" from suspended state, just turn option `turn screen of when inactive` off.

At least it worked for me.  Its not solution for the problem but it makes problem bearable

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run these commands

Remove existing xorg using the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
```

Install xorg using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

Reconfigure xorg using the following command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

saw it one one website, fixed problem for me